# How to make a sub use global variable value specifically from another sub (being set different values in other subs)

Tags: vb6

I have a global variable and its value is being changed constantly depending on what the user does

When my app enters this sub, i want it to use the value from a specific sub elsewhere in the project

Help?

Using VB6

Comment: That sounds contradictory. If anyone can change it, how can you guarantee that the value was set by a particular sub? Maybe you need to re-think the global nature of this variable, or add another variable that tracks where the value came from?

Comment: @JimMack this is because when i hit a button, the global variable changes for its needs. But the follow up action needs to use the global variables value before it needed to change. My current work around though its not the best since it needs extra lines of code everywhere is to make another global variable and use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SUB or FUNCTION you can add a **Optional** parameter with default value. I.e.:

' on BAS module

```
Public gsMyVar As String
Public Sub MakeSomething(Optional ByVal pMyVar As String = vbNullString)
    If pMyVar = vbNullString Then
        pMyVar = gsMyVar
    End If
    MsgBox "LOCAL MyVar is now: " & pMyVar
End Sub
```

' on FRM module

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    gsMyVar = "BLA-BLA-BLA"
    MsgBox "Global MyVar is : " & gsMyVar
    MakeSomething "YES"
End Sub
```